# M13Checkbox Selected Action in Swift?

Tags: swift, checkbox

I'm using the M13Checkbox pod. I want to print "remember me" to labeltextfield when checkbox is checked, and "remember me" when Checkbox is not checked. When I click it, it just says, "don't remember me."

```
  let checkboxm13: M13Checkbox = {

        let checkboxe = M13Checkbox()
        checkboxe.stateChangeAnimation = .stroke
        checkboxe.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxvalue(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return checkboxe

    }()
 @objc func checkboxvalue(sender: Checkbox) {
        if sender.isSelected == true {
            labelcheckbox.text = ("Beni Hatırla")

        }
        if sender.isSelected == false {
            labelcheckbox.text = ("Hatırlama")           
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `checkState` not `isSelected`

```
@objc func checkboxvalue(_ sender: M13checkbox) {
    switch sender.checkState {
        case .checked:
            labelcheckbox.text = "Beni Hatırla"
        break

        case .unchecked:
            labelcheckbox.text = "Hatırlama"    
        break

        case .mixed:
            //empty...
        break       
    }       
}
```